# Axios response data is undefined while the request is succesful

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
    function confirmPassword() {
    let password = document.getElementById("password").value
    let email = document.getElementById("email").value

    Service.confirmPassword(email, password).then(response => {
        res = response.data
        setTwoFactorStep(1)
    }).catch(err => {
        alert(err.data.message)
    })
    alert(res)
}
```

After the request is done, `response.data` is undefined, while I can check my browser it was succesful, and the body is present. If I alert `response.data` inside the `.then` I get an `Object object`

OBS: The var `res` is declared before, and the method `Service.confirmPassword` is a axios.post.

Comment: what type of data you are expecting from api

Comment: I'm expecting a JSON in the body.

Comment: then parse it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted isn't synchronous
the alert will trigger before your http request has a chance to resolve which is probably why you get an undefined. if you want to do anything with the response body you should probably do it within the 'then' callback.

```
function confirmPassword() {
    let password = document.getElementById("password").value
    let email = document.getElementById("email").value

// 1.your service call through axios gets triggered
    Service.confirmPassword(email, password).then(response => {
      // 3.this gets execute after the alert below once the http request has been resolved
        res = response.data 
        setTwoFactorStep(1);
    // invoke your handler here...
    }).catch(err => {
        alert(err.data.message)
    })
    alert(res) // 2.this gets executed next
}
```

if you want to write this in a synchronous way, consider using async/await

```
 async function confirmPassword() {
    let password = document.getElementById("password").value
    let email = document.getElementById("email").value

    const response = await Service.confirmPassword(email, password).catch(err => alert(err.data.message));
    res = response.data;
    setTwoFactorStep(1);
    alert(res)
```